# Quickfix engine - does it persist messages before the start time on the server side

Tags: quickfix

If a quick fix session is created by server(acceptor) at say 9AM, but the StartTime is at 11AM. This means the session exists but not active.

If the server receives an unsolicited message from an exchange that it needs to send on this session, will it persist this if I have configuration PersistMessages=Y and sends it to the client(initiator) when it connects after 11AM?

Comment: I think it probably will, but why don't you try it and tell us for sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not persist messages received before start time and would send you a reject message. The message will be rejected at the interface itself, message isn't handled. You would have to resend it to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

QuickFIX does persist (but not send) messages before a session is connected. The sequence numbers are updated and when the session is connected and the first message is sent, the counterparty FIX engine will see the gap in the sequence numbers and request a resend. QuickFIX will then resend the persisted messages. However, depending on your QuickFIX configuration, the outgoing messages might be considered to be too old and rejected locally.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, these are kept to take into account timings under which corresponding exchange would accept the orders. 
Application or its sub-modules do not need to maintain timings and take some action on closing the fix session. Rather, QuickFix shall automatically deactivate the session.
Persistence of the message or re-sesnding when the session becomes active does not look desirable to me.

You can rather maintain some kind of queue to buffer such messages in sending application, and send them only when the time matches with active session timings.

That's my thoughts, hope that helps.